# What is the equivalent of \[ ... \] in zsh?

Tags: bash, zsh

In my **.bashrc** file, when I colour the prompt, I use `\[ ... \]` to prevent new bash lines overwriting previous ones (also prevent writing buffer overflow/underflow or cases when text being typed in random locations). This only happens when using colours. In my **.bashrc** file I have:

```
WHITE="\[$(tty -s && tput setaf 254)\]";

PS1+="${WHITE} @ "
```

But `\[` escapes don't work on **zsh** in **.zshrc**

How can I fix this please?

Comment: I think you're looking for `%{...%}`

Comment: `zsh` has a lot more built-in escapes that already "know" they occupy zero width. For example, use `PS1+="%F{white} @ "`.

Comment: Thank you Will this is correct and it works okay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `zsh` equivalent is `%{ ... %}`. However, it's not needed as frequently because `zsh` has a much richer set of prompt escapes that eliminate the need to use raw escape sequences. For example, the `%F` escape lets you select a foreground color by  name or number. `zsh` already knows how to query your terminal for the exact bytes to use, and `zsh` also knows that those bytes should not count towards the width of the prompt.

```
PS1+="%F{white} @ "
```

or

```
PS1+="%F{254} @ "
```